# Run application nohup-like

Tags: command-line, nohup

Currently I have command `pycharm` to start Pycharm IDE. I use it like `sudo pycharm` and this launches Pycharm, but I have to keep terminal from where I've launched it open, because if I close it Pycharm being closed too.

Question is following.

How can I launch Pycharm(or any other application) and be able to close terminal from where it was launched?
I tried `nohup pycharm &` but with no result. I need to run it with sudo

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to run a python IDE with sudo (especially not plain sudo, which is not meant for GUI applications) - can you explain why you need to do that? **Without** sudo, you could use the bash built-in disown command i.e. `pycharm & disown`.

Comment: If I run it as regular user I can not update from version control

Answer (score 1):

Try the `setsid` command of syntax:

```
setsid program [arg...]
```

so in your case:

```
setsid pycharm
```

From `man setsid`

```
       setsid - run a program in a new session
```

for example: `setsid firefox`

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gksudo pycharm or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> kdesu pycharm `if you are running kde org gnome, but probably there really is no reason to run it as root.